# Map Spatial Reference

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, coordinate-system, arcgis-online-basemaps

I was having some trouble when trying to zoom to certain point in ESRI base map. So basically I got an ESRI base map and added a map overlay on top of it:

```
function setMap() {
function init() {
    require(
        [
            "esri/map",
            "dojo/dom-construct",
            "esri/geometry/Point", 
            "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
            "esri/graphic", "esri/Color",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ],
        function 
        (
            Map, domConstruct, Point,
            SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol,
            Graphic, Color
        ) {
            map = Map("map-canvas",
            {
            });
            map.setZoom(0);
            coreFunctions();
        });
}
dojo.ready(init);
gsvc = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");
}
```

Here is the part for me to add map overlay with wkid:3414:

```
function addLayersToData() {
var layer = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("https://www.onemap.sg/ArcGIS/rest/services/BASEMAP/MapServer");
mapLayers.push(layer);
```

}

And then I got a function to zoom to certain point of the map:

```
function zoomPostal(postalCode) {
 $.getJSON("http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/basicSearch?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&searchVal="
                        + postalCode
                        + "&otptFlds=SEARCHVAL,CATEGORY&returnGeom=0&rset=1", function (data) {

    var loc = new esri.geometry.Point({ "x": data.SearchResults[1].X, "y": data.SearchResults[1].Y, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 3414 } });           
    console.log(data.SearchResults[1].X);   
    console.log(data.SearchResults[1].Y);
    map.centerAndZoom(loc,1);
    });
}
```

When I print out the X and Y, I am getting: 23948.7465,47505.7986. And I am getting these error message after I tried to zoom to certain point:

```
Map: Geometry (wkid: 3414) cannot be converted to spatial reference of the map (wkid: PROJCS["SVY21",GEOGCS["SVY21[WGS84]",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",28001.642],PARAMETER["False_Northing",38744.572],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",103.8333333333333],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",1.366666666666667],UNIT["Meter",1.0]])
```

I have no idea how to solve this. Any ideas?

Basically if I added these code to see the conversion of the coordinate by plotting a marker, it works as in the marker did shows up. Just that I cannot zoom to that point:

```
var mrtIcon = [];
    var symbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol('img/transportation/mrt_marker.PNG', 30, 30);
    var PointGraphic = new esri.Graphic(loc, symbol);
    map.graphics.add(PointGraphic);

    var graphic = PointGraphic;
    graphic.setSymbol(symbol);
    mrtIcon.push(map.graphics.add(graphic));
    map.centerAt(loc);
```

**EDIT**

```
var x =  data.SearchResults[1].X;
     console.log(x);
     var y =  data.SearchResults[1].Y;
     console.log(y);
    var loc = new esri.geometry.Point({ 
        "x": x, 
        "y": y, 
        "spatialReference":'PROJCS["SVY21",GEOGCS["SVY21[WGS84]",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",28001.642],PARAMETER["False_Northing",38744.572],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",103.8333333333333],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",1.366666666666667],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]' });           

    map.centerAndZoom(loc, 5);
```

So I got variable x and y which hold the same value as your hardcoded x and y coordinates. It does not work if I put it this way, it only work when I hardcoded the x and y with coordinates like your solutions. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to supply a geotransformation to project from SVY21 to EPSG:3414? I'm not familiar with either... Just because they are the same doesn't mean they *are* the same: one is as WKT the other is EPSG - the software may not see them as being the same. Can you force your overlay to use the EPSG (Factory Code) rather than Well Known Text?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Sorry but I don't get what you mean. Would you mind to provide me with some examples? Because so far when I plot markers using this method, it's working perfectly. Just that when I tried to zoom to the point on the map, then I will get this error message.

Comment: @PolyGeo Hello PolyGeo, any ideas to fix this? I have no problem on plotting the markers using this method. The error message only appear when I tried to zoom to certain point on the map

Comment: I don't program with the ArcGIS API for JavaScript so I cannot help personally.  However I have just retagged it to try and throw your question into the path of those that follow the [tag:arcgis-javascript-api] tag.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I've edited my code to see if the conversion went well by plotting a marker with that coordinate. The marker did shows up but I just can't zoom to that point on the map

Comment: I'm in the same boat as PolyGeo: I don't do java. I know that ArcMap has an issue with coordinate systems that aren't interchangeable, which oft happens if you use WKT, the EPSG is more reliable if you can enforce it.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I see. But do you have any idea how to enforce the basemap as you suggested?

Comment: I don't think there's much you can change about the basemap. Have a look at the objects' spatial reference property and see if it's read/write or read only. The map usually has a spatial reference property which is read/write and you can modify the spatial reference of your feature data to match the base map.

Answer (score 3):

@Michael Miles-Stimson was on track w/ his first comment.

since your ArcGIS Tiled Map Service defines its own projection using [WKT](http://www.onemap.sg/ArcGIS/rest/services/BASEMAP/MapServer?f=json) (as opposed to WKID), you need to use an identical projection definition in your code to indicate to the JSAPI that the point you are passing is in the same coordinate system as the map.

check out a working [jsbin](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59331579/js/wkt-point.html) here

another alternative would be to republish the map service, making sure to define the projection as explicitly wkid:3414.

edit: from the jsbin i linked above:

```
var point = new Point({
  "x": 23948.7465,
  "y": 47505.7986, 
  "spatialReference":'PROJCS["SVY21",GEOGCS["SVY21[WGS84]",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",28001.642],PARAMETER["False_Northing",38744.572],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",103.8333333333333],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",1.366666666666667],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]'
});
```

Comment: So basically what should I changed for the zoomToPostal function? I am a little bit confused.

Comment: i've updated my answer to include a code snippet from the example application i included initially.  hope it helps.

Comment: How come it only works when I hardcode the coordinates x and y like yours? It does not work if I replace the coordinate x to data.SearchResults[1].X; It told me Error: Invalid value for <image> attribute x="NaN" but then when I print it out, it did shows the exact coordinates as your x

Comment: Check my edited portion, sorry for the poor explanation above :(

Answer (score 0):

when your map is being drawn with a spatialReference based by yourself, you need to create a point object (with the same spatialReference) and pass the point as the center in the map constructor. as the following:

```
var point = new Point({
    "x": 575442.9940072033,
    "y": 383796.1914205253, 
    "spatialReference":'PROJCS["BJ-city",GEOGCS["GCS_Beijing_1954",DATUM["D_Beijing_1954",SPHEROID["Krasovsky_1940",6378245.0,298.3]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",300000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",116.3502518],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",39.86576603],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]'
});
map.centerAndZoom(point,5);
```